# Why is a triangular cavity created during wire-cutting of an organic gel?

Tags: gel

I conduct wire-cutting on a gel made with organic oil. When I use high cutting rates, the wire cuts the gel in half leaving two smooth cutting surfaces. In contrast, when I use a very low cutting rate, the oil inside the gel starts coming out and a cavity is also formed around the wire (as if, instead of cutting the fibers, the wire compresses the gel network and pushes the oil out). I'm wondering why the cavity is triangular.

[image]

Comment: I really hope someone could come up with a simulated CAD model illustrating displacement map–[elastic modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus) dependency and not a generic hand-waving explanation. I think we have a couple more of similar questions, and it would be nice to have a canonical answer for this type of questions.